# Java class extends MainActivity but findViewById comes back null?

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

This class extends my main Activity.

```
public class Numbers extends MainActivity{

public ArrayList<ImageView> getNumbers () {
    ArrayList<ImageView> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    ImageView one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
    numbers.add(one);
    return numbers;
}
```

And I've done some digging but can figure out why my variable "one" is coming back null.
My MainActivity has a ContentView set.

This is the content of my `onCreate` in MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView start = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.start);
    sceneRoot = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scene_root);
    questionView = findViewById(R.id.questionView);
    startView = findViewById(R.id.startView);
    gameOverView = findViewById(R.id.gameOver);

    animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide);
    animSlide.setAnimationListener(this);
    animZoom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom_fade);
    animZoom.setAnimationListener(this);

    set.addTransition(new Fade())
       .addTransition(new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT));

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getQuestion();
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot, set);
            startView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            questionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

public void getQuestion (){
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeBar);
    time.startAnimation(animSlide);
}
```

I don't call `getNumbers()` until after start has been clicked and the animation has started.

```
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){
    if(animation == animSlide) {
        final Questions questions = new Questions();

        Numbers n = new Numbers();

        for (int i = 0; i < n.getNumbers().size(); i++) {
            n.getNumbers().get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            n.getNumbersTen().get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        n.getNumbers().get(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

EDIT:

If anyone was wondering, I got it to work by extending the class as a Fragment instead of my MainActivity. Then I just used the fragment in my xml.

Comment: Can you show the name and content of your view?

Comment: Show your code for activity and layout...And check if you call `getNumbers()` before `setContentView`

Comment: probably because `one` is initialized inside `onCreate` of `MainActivity`

Comment: my view content is pretty lengthy. It is basically an activity_main with a few <include>s and one of the views has a lot of <ImageView>s with the id tags of "one" or "two" etc. If you still need to see it I can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you extended an Activity class doesn't mean `setContentView` gets called for that class also. It will only do so if properly started and you call `super.onCreate(bundle)` from your own implementation of `onCreate` within `Numbers`

Basically, you should **never** `new` any Activity. It has no life-cycle, and therefore no content view, so `findViewById` just won't work.

```
Numbers n = new Numbers();
```

---

You could not extend anything and have a data-only class around your list of images.

```
public class Numbers {
    private List<ImageView> numbers = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    public Numbers() {}
    public void addNumber(ImageView v) { numbers.add(v); }
    public List<ImageView> getNumbers() { return numbers; }
}
```

And *from MainActivity* you can find and add as you want.

```
Number n = new Numbers();
n.addNumber((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one));
```

However, I don't know if that is useful, really...

Maybe a Fragment would serve a better purpose if you want a "sub-view" of your Activity, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: So if I extend with Fragment how would I go about setting up the content view?

Comment: I don't know how your layouts are related. All I'm saying is that you have to call `findViewById` from a class that actual contains the layout you need to find from.